# How to force mac screenreader to automatically read heading text in a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

So I have a SPA angular 1.5 app and when the user navigates to a new page sometimes the page doesn't have any inputs that are autofocused, for example it is just a congratulations page saying the user was successful in registering. I've been able to come up with a slightly hacky solution by doing

$('.registration-confirmation').attr("tabIndex", 0).focus();

so the screenreader automatically reads out the text in the registration confirmation div, but then I also had to prevent the blue outline in the css from the focus

.registration-confirmation {
    &:focus {
        outline: 0; // remove webkit injected outline on focus
    }
}

Is there a simpler way to do this? with maybe aria attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, stop doing it like that - not good accessibility at all, especially since you've now confused me by messing with the focus indicator.  ARIA roles are the correct way to handle this:

- If you're trying to report an error, this should get [ARIA `role="alert"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#alert), which will immediately get announced by the screen reader and is invasive so should not be used liberally.
- For success reporting or other progress, you can use [ARIA `role="status"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#status); however, still don't abuse it.  If the user jumps to a successful registration screen with next steps, for example, applying it to anything but a simple "congratulations" would be inappropriate.

I suggest looking at the ARIA best practices document for various example uses.

Comment: I tried 
<h1 role="status" class="text-center">Congratulations</h1>

and it didn't work (screenreader didn't read anything out) but

<h1 role="alert" class="text-center">Congratulations</h1>
did work

Comment: That's typical.  The status role is generally used for things like progress bars or equivalent text updates (e.g. "Preparing", "Installing", then "Done"), but it will only continuously announce if I keep focus on it.  An alert on the other hand, will interrupt something else I'm doing to let me know I need to take action.  That's why it should be used sparingly for errors or similar events.